# Objective-C: stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfStringwithString and stringByAppendingString not working

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have an NSString that I am trying to use to load a webpage on a Web View in XCode.  However, I need to replace spaces in the NSString with underscores, and I also need to replace all apostrophes with "%27".  Then, I need to append onto the end of the fullURL NSString.  Whenever it executes the part of code that makes the NSString replacements, nothing gets replaced.  It stays the same as the original NSString.  When I try to append, it does not append.

**The .h file:**

```
@interface WikipediaViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString* artistName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end
```

**The method with the NSString replacements and append in it:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *fullURL = @"en.wikipedia.org/wiki/";

    [artistName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"_"];
    [artistName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"%27"];
    [fullURL stringByAppendingString:artistName];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

Oh, also, the artistName variable is being initialized from a different class, so just assume that it already contains information.

Can anyone tell me why this is not working?  Thanks.

Comment: I would hazard to guess they're working exactly as designed.  Look at the spec for the two functions to see why your code doesn't work.

Comment: Why don't you read the documentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[artistName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"_"];
```

actually returns a string that you need to capture, so do.

```
NSString *myNewString = [artistName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"    " withString:@"_"];
```

Strings are immutable in many languages so methods do not actually modify the underlying string.

Comment: Thanks!  I knew it was something stupid, and it's always good to have another set of eyes.

Comment: @JoeyKleingers You should probably accept it as an answer then.

Comment: Notice it won't work just using that. Change the property's weak attribute too (see my answer).

Answer (score 2):

First, your property is a weak property, which most likely is wrong. Make it copy instead of weak. Then, instead of writing artistName to access the iVar use self.artistName to access the getter (this is best practice).

Secondly - and most importantly - assign the returned value of stringByReplacing... to your iVar through the setter (ie self.artistName again). 
Right now you just call the method which does nothing, since it doesnt change the string per se, it gives a new instance of a string with the changes made. in your case, the return value is never used.

So, use

```
self.artistName = [self.artistName stringByReplacing.....];
```

and

```
fullURL = [fullURL stringByAppending....];
```

But since artistName is a weak property, the string will be gone and so not be appended to your fileURL.

So make your property copy

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *artistName;
```

(I wonder why your code works in the first place because with the newest Xcode and compiler versions your property should be automatically synthesised to have an underscore-prefixed iVar (ie _artistName in your case). So writing just artistName shouldn't work, unless you synthesized it that way.)

Answer (score 1):

I have edited your code to make it work

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSString *fullURL = @"en.wikipedia.org/wiki/";

artistName = [artistName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"_"];
artistName = [artistName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"%27"];
fullURL = [fullURL stringByAppendingString:artistName];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

Remember that stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString returns a string which you have to save somewhere, replacing the old artistName string with the new one makes sense in your case.